# Looking for the name of this type of grammatical term "im-", "mis-"

Tags: grammar, suffixes, prefixes, morphology

We can break some words in two or three parts. Example:

> Impossible = Im + possible
>
> Misconception = Miss + conception

What does these type of grammatical term called?

PS:I'm looking for this, because I'm trying to learn vocabulary and found that this way would be easier for me.

Comment: Please wait at least a day before accepting an answer. You may get other answers which will give you different ideas, facts or points of view! If you accept an answer you won't get many answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From more general to more specific,

- word formation (making new words)
- word derivation (making new words out of other words)
- word prefixation (making new words by putting stuff in front of an existing word or root)

**in-** and **mis-** are called a *prefix*, as opposed to *-ness* or *-ly* which would be examples of a *suffix*. There are also other kinds of *affixes*, rarer or missing in English.

Comment: Helpful. Do you know any reliable website like Wiktionary for these, from where I can learn words?

Comment: I found this, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-formation

but i need the full dictionary.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_prefixes , http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_prefixes , http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_suffixes

Answer (score 4):

The different parts of words that have different meanings are called *MORPHEMES*. A morpheme is the smallest part of a word that has its own meaning. So the morphemes in the word *reviewed* are:

- re (meaning *again*)
- view  (meaning *see*)
- ed (usually indicating *past*)

Sometimes there is a main part of the word, which we call the *BASE* or the *ROOT*. Bits that go before the root are often called *PREFIXES*. Bits that go after the root are called *SUFFIXES*.

In English, prefixes usually change the actual meaning of a word. So if we change *like* to **dis**like, it has the opposite meaning.

Suffixes *usually* have two possible functions.One is to show grammatical inflections. This means they show us whether a word is singular or plural, or whether a verb, for instance is present tense or past tense. We call this kind of morphology *INFLECTIONAL MORPHOLOGY* and suffixes like *-s* or *-ed* are called *inflectional morphemes*.

The second main function of suffixes in English is to change the type of word. So, for example, suffixes often change a verb into a noun, or noun into an adjective:

- elec**tion** (*-tion* usually changes verbs into nouns. Here we have the verb *elect* and the noun *election*)
- colour**ful** (*-ful* usually changes nouns into adjectives. Here we have the noun *colour* and the adjective *colourful*).

If you understand the difference between the different jobs that prefixes, roots and suffixes do, it can help you to guess the meanings of new words.